# Page scrolls up and down with reloads

Tags: html, google-chrome, scroll

When I scroll down to any position, and then reload the page, it moves down, another reload: moves more down, another reload moves up. I do not touch my scroll wheel at all.

Why does this happen? It only happens with one of my websites.

I saw it happen in Chrome. This does not happen in Firefox. Not sure about other browsers.

Just in case, I use Open Sans in my page. So that means external fonts.
Maybe external fonts cause this. My other website without external fonts does not do this.

### Edit:

All I can say is that I use jQuery. And this is the only code I have that uses JS/jQuery:

```
var xy = document.getElementById("nav");
if (xy.className === "nav") {
  xy.className = "navdispnone";
} else {
  xy.className = "nav";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navdispnonebtn').click(function(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById("nav");
    if (x.className === "navdispnone") {
      x.className = "nav";
    } else {
      x.className = "navdispnone";
    }
  });
});
```

It hides and shows nav bar with click on button.

Comment: Showing us related code could be helpful.

Comment: @DanWoda, but its huge. So, I think it would be better for someone to help me if this is a common issue for them and if they know the fix for it.